# linux c++ application deployment

Tags: c++, log4cxx

I am trying to deploy a c++ application with log4cxx.so and is requiring glibc 2.14, but the machine being deploy has 2.12 glibc. Is is necessary to upgrade this machine to glibc 2.14 in order to run this application? Or there is other more portable way?

Comment: You could try statically linking the library.  Google should turn up the "how to" info.

Comment: this might help: [How compatible are different versions of glibc?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107263/how-compatible-are-different-versions-of-glibc

Comment: Then, if it's too hard to deploy a new version of glibc, statically link your executable.

Comment: I am trying to statically link log4cxx. I got the log4cxx.a, but i dont have the static lib for the apr, and apr-util (log4cxx dependency), i only have their .so. do you guys know how to statically link log4cxx?

Comment: @phoeagon: It is **ILLEGAL** to link glibc to a **closed-source** program statically (license requires LGPL on all statically linked code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux binary portability is a pain. Linux uses symbol versioning, so you should be able to find out what symbols are needed with:

```
nm binary | grep @@GLIBC_ | sort -t@ -k14
```

You may be able to inline the functions and remove the dependency on newer `glibc`.

You can read more [here](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/linux_binary_compatibility.html). Generally the best option for portability is to compile against an older version of `glibc` or just to provide sources and a `MAKEFILE`.